# I'm having trouble with HTTPS redirect in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I'm having trouble using this code to redirect my users to HTTPS while including the subfolder/file after the domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tix\.kiwi [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

If I manually enter http://tix.kiwi/atd in my address bar, the browser redirects to https://tix.kiwiatd instead of https://tix.kiwi/atd/ and if I go to https://tix.kiwi/atd directly then it loads fine.

This same code works fine on my other websites; why is it not working here?

Notes: I'm using DigitalOcean, Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: Try clearing browser cache.

Comment: I kind of feel like it's an issue with browsers handling the .kiwi domain?

Comment: Is this in your htaccess file or apache config?

Comment: Apache config actually- does it work different than if I put it in htaccess?

Comment: Try adding a slash in front of the rewriterule `^/(.*)$` and restart apache if it's in your apache config.

Comment: Well if you “lose” the slash between host name and request URI during your rewrite – wouldn’t it then be the next logical thing to try and put one in there, just for laughs …? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: still not working with the slash added, and restarting apache of course

Comment: Well then enable rewrite logging, so that you can retrace what is actually going on.

Comment: Depending on your server/domain setup, maybe setting a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) might be necessary.

Comment: You could also just omit the vars and use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tik.kiwi/$1 [R=301,L]` Since it's your site just make the rewrite specific to your needs.

Comment: @PanamaJack still not working, also I have no idea how to enable rewrite logging - I tried googling it but I can't seem to find where the log file is when using 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 LogLevel mod_rewrite.c:trace8
</IfModule>`

The log file stated on the website associated with that code doesn't show anything about my https redirect

Comment: What browser are you using? are you sure you restarted apache and cleared your cache. Try another browser.

Comment: Safari, Chrome, Firefox

Comment: yes, I am restarting apache and clearing the cache

Comment: In addistion to useing loglevel you you also should include the path to where you want the log to be written too. You make the path. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog And I would use level 9 while debugging.

Comment: I did not include that because of this: AH00526: Syntax error on line 98 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: I'm on apache 2.4.7 - so the RewriteLog command does not exist - so how do I find the log file?

Comment: Then you are using the wrong directive for logging for 2.4. It's supposed to be something like this `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8` and then you need to look at your apache error log for info on that. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: rewrite still not showing up in apache error log

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII It seems to be a caching issue for sure as your rewrite is working fine here.

Comment: Nope, I found the issue. It had to do with a redirect I had set on another virtualhost- even though the server name did not match

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrites look correct, your issue lies in additional redirect code on another virtual host.  Resolving the conflict at that level allowed this rewrite to work as intented.  As discussed in the comments